# JLabels becoming really small

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I'm using a gridbaglayout for a Java project of mine and for some reason when I launch the program all the JLabels seem to be really small even though I've sized them using percentages(thus the sizing should be relative)

Here is the code I used to set the preferred size:

```
int stswidth = (int)(((float)66/100) * getWidth()), stsheight = (int)(((float)65/100) * getHeight()); 
int navwidth = (int)(((float)21.5f/100) * getWidth()), navheight = (int)(((float)10/100) * getHeight());
int clwidth = (int)(((float)25/100) * getWidth()), clheight = (int)(((float)80/100) * getHeight());
int hwidth = (int)(((float)100/100) * getWidth()), hheight = (int)(((float)20/100) * getHeight());
```

Here is the code to set the position of each label using grid bag constraints:

```
c = new GridBagConstraints();

   c.gridx = 0;
   c.gridy = 0;

   core.add(sts[1], c);

   //nav

   c.gridx = 0;
   c.gridy = 0;

   nav.add(navb[0], c);

   c.gridx = 1;
   c.gridy = 0;

   nav.add(navb[1], c);

   c.gridx = 2;
   c.gridy = 0;

   nav.add(navb[2], c);

   //cl

   c.gridx = 0; 
   c.gridy = 0;

   clock.add(cl, c);
   head.add(header, c);
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue, question, for why hells on this world you calculate Dimension, logics implemented in LayoutManagers for Swing is JComponents return own size to container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set preferred width. Use `weightx` and `weighty`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see where you're setting any of the constraints weightx and weighty. Try giving them default values of 1.0.

```
c = new GridBagConstraints();

c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
```

This will help prevent all the components from scrunching up in the center.
And yeah, if this doesn't help, then create and post your [sscce](http://sscce.org).